# Very simple static website with Google Analytics. How to make it GDPR compliant?

Tags: internet, gdpr, european-union

There is a very simple static website for a commerce. That website only shows information. It has Google Analytics to count visits with the default GA script placed in :

```
<head>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
</head>
```

As you can see, is the default script that google gives you for a simple integration of GA in your website, and it's placed in the default place (header).

**Now it haves a lower bar displaying this:**

> This website uses 'cookies' for your navigation. By using our services you accept their use.
> If you want to restrict the use of cookies, click on More information.

That bar has two buttons, "Accept" and "More information". Accept simply hides the bar forever, and more information displays the legal info of the commerce and tells the users that it is using google analytics to track the visits, and that Google Analytics uses cookies. It also tells the user that they can remove the cookies and prevent the website collecting cookies disabling it in the navigator, and gives the user some links with official help about how to disable and remove cookies for a website in four big navigators (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari).

Is enough with that to be compliant with GDPR in this very simple website which only uses GA to track visits?

Comment: "This website uses 'cookies' for your navigation. By using our services you accept their use. If you want to restrict the use of cookies, click on More information." - well thats false, surely, because the cookie and personal identifiers that Google Analytics will add are used for tracking and analytics, not navigation...

Comment: Note that we cannot give specific legal advice here.  This is bordering on asking for legal advice, though it might be okay.

Comment: @Moo what is your proposal?